# Empty Pdf file generated with FPDF library in WordPress plugin

Tags: plugin-development, pdf

I am currently implementing a pdf export functionality within a wordpress plugin i'm developing but the pdf file generated when i click on export button is empty. To implement the export i use [FPDF library](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Ive put the code which uses FPDF in a function which is executed by the wp_ajax_ action hook. Here is the code:

```
<?php

require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'fpdf/fpdf.php';

function pdf_pull_wpse_212972() {

  $pdf = new FPDF('p','mm','a4');
  $pdf->SetFont('arial','b',14);
  $pdf->AddPage();
  $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Referrer URL',1,0,'C');
  $pdf->Cell(40,10,'User IP Address',1,0,'C');
  $pdf->Cell(40,10,'User Agent',1,0,'C');
  $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Browser',1,0,'C');
  $pdf->Cell(40,10,'OS',1,0,'C');
  $pdf->Output();

  wp_die();

}

add_action('wp_ajax_pdf_pull','pdf_pull_wpse_212972');
```

Here is the jQuery code executed when i click on the export button

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  
  jQuery('#pdf-export-btn').click(function(){

    var data = {
      'action': 'pdf_pull',
    };
    
    jQuery.post(tclisecure.ajax_url, data, function(response) {


        var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        var fileData = [response];

        var blobObject = new Blob(fileData,{
            type: "application/pdf"
          });

        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blobObject);
        downloadLink.href = url;
        downloadLink.download = "tracked_info.pdf";

        /*
        * Actually download PDF
        */
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        downloadLink.click();
        document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
      
    });

  });


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not solve the problem, but what you're currently doing looks unnecessarily convoluted (ajax request, fake link, serve PDF via link click etc.)

Why not just a link styled as a button...

```html
<a class="button" href="<?= admin_url( 'admin-post.php?action=wpse_212972_pdf' ) ?>">Download</a>
```

...and then serve the PDF as a download directly from the server (using WP's generic POST/GET handler `admin-post.php`):

```php
function wpse_212972_pdf() {
    $pdf = new FPDF('p','mm','a4');
    $pdf->SetFont('arial','b',14);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Referrer URL',1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'User IP Address',1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'User Agent',1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Browser',1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'OS',1,0,'C');

    // http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm
    $pdf->Output( 'D', 'tracked_info.pdf' );
    exit;
}

add_action( 'admin_post_wpse_212972_pdf', 'wpse_212972_pdf' );

// Non-logged-in users (remove if not required)
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_wpse_212972_pdf', 'wpse_212972_pdf' );
```